# Symfony 4.2 VichUploaderBundle: File not saved

Tags: symfony, upload, entity, vichuploaderbundle

I'm using **VichUploaderBundle** in my application to upload the files.

Problem is that even if I followed the docs, the file isn't uploaded (even if seems to be all right, as profiles sais), and no rows was make in the entity table.

Here is my **vich_uploader.yaml**:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        media:
            uri_prefix: /media
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/media'
            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

Here is my **Media Entity**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="media", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $imageSize;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        if (null !== $imageFile) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }
    }

    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    public function setImageName(?string $imageName): void
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;
    }

    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    public function setImageSize(?int $imageSize): void
    {
        $this->imageSize = $imageSize;
    }

    public function getImageSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->imageSize;
    }
}
```

I just need to store the file in the entity, there is no relations between files and other entities.

Here is my **MediaType**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Media;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class MediaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'download_uri' => true

            ])

            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ],
                'label' => 'Upload File'
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Media::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The **Form** is handled by this Twig template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form.imageFile) }}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    {{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, that was an edit i've made to try things work, that no change behaviour

Comment: @msg, changing to `media` doesn't change anything, any other ideas?

Comment: @msg I've add the `createdAt` property but nothing change, nothing in the logs. Filesystem permissions are ok, the same user exec the server and got permission to write (same thing on my production server). I think I miss something, should i have something in my controller that I miss? Who is calling Doctrine?

Comment: You didn't show the controller, but it's pretty standard, `handle` the form and `flush` the entity if `isValid`.

Comment: Ok, I think I miss this part, there is nothing about handle the submission in the docs, so I was thinking about the bundle thinks about all.

Comment: Check [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms) and adjust for your entities.

Comment: @msg It's working now! Thank you a lot! I was missing the namer too.

Comment: The namer is not *strictly* necessary, if not specified it'll upload the file with the same name as uploaded. But is handy to avoid collisions.